# How to resolve - line reader skipping lines while reading

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am reading a file using line reader but its skipping lines.
How to resolve this issue.

```
 fileReader = new FileReader(fileEntry);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
 lineReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
 String eachLineForAFile ;
 while ((eachLineForAFile = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(lineReader.getLineNumber());
     dosomething();
 }
```

Its skipping lines while reading and when I am printing the line no. its showing alternate line number.

Comment: Should `lineReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);` be `lineReader = new LineNumberReader(br);`? And does `doSomething()` do anything with either `filereader`, `br`, or `lineReader`?

Comment: Input sample please. And actual output.

Comment: doSomething() means doing something using eachLineForAFile.

Comment: The output of the System.out.println(lineReader.getLineNumber()) is  provided below:                                                                                                                      1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
27
29
31
33....

Comment: Input is as important as output here.